# Roughly what percentage (by cost) of a Rocket Launch does stage 1 of the Falcon 9 Rocket represent?

Tags: rockets, spacex, landing, cost, cost-to-orbit

As of a short time ago, SpaceX made history as the first entity *ever* to successfully re-land the initial stage of an orbital rocket.

Up until this point, the dominating factor in the cost of Rocket Launches has been that you have to build a new Rocket for every launch (about \$50 Million for a Falcon 9 launch, I've seen estimates of \$10 - \$20 Million purely to manufacture the rocket), whereas a typical launch burns just $200,000 of fuel.

If, in theory, Falcon 9 can continually re-use its initial rocket stage without having to build a new one each time, how much might this reduce the cost of a Rocket Launch by?

Comment: Answered here: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8330/what-is-the-cost-breakdown-for-a-falcon-9-launch

Comment: I quibble with your premise; depending on how you define "initial stage", the US space shuttle accomplished this in 1982.

Comment: How about \*In one piece\* then? IIRC, the shuttle only ever managed to recover the booster rockets from its' launches, and only after they'd already detached from the main rocket body (The huge orange tank thing).

Answer (score 3):

It depends really, on a number of factors that we simply don't know right now. From [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8461/25), we know that the propellant is only about 0.3% of the cost of the launch. Furthermore, the first stage is about 3/4th of the cost of the rocket. So, what will the cost be of a re-used rocket?

Well, first of all, the lifetime is currently estimated at around 10 launches per rocket. The cost of the booster is around 75% of the cost. Fuel is negligible. A certain amount of cost is fixed in the mission planning aspects, which I suspect costs around $1 million (Quite possibly less, but let's just go with that). All in all, I imagine the cost of a re-used rocket would be about 35% of a non-reused rocket, give or take.

Bigger than the propellant cost, especially for the first attempts, will be the re-certification cost. A significant part of any space mission is this aspect. I would give this a 15% overall mission cost for the first few attempts, and less of a cost for all future missions.

Comment: In June 2015, SES was on record as being not only willing, but eager,  to launch on a re-used Falcon if it got them a good discount: http://spacenews.com/spacex-early-adopter-ses-ready-to-reuse-falcon-9-%C2%AD-for-the-right-price/

Comment: Your doubts have already been signed away on a [contract](http://spacenews.com/spacex-early-adopter-ses-ready-to-reuse-falcon-9-%C2%AD-for-the-right-price/) *"Satellite fleet operator SES on June 17 said it wants to reuse the first stage of the SpaceX Falcon 9 rocket"* It is safer to use a rocket which has been proven to work, than some unproven newbuild which might have all its gyros installed upside down (like a Proton the other year).

Comment: @LocalFluff: Safer has yet to be determined. Interesting information, I wasn't ware of it. I decided to just remove that bit, however, as it wasn't important.