# How much fuel does the Falcon Heavy use? What is the price RP-1?

Tags: spacex, fuel, falcon-heavy, cost

Does anyone know how much fuel the Falcon Heavy can hold, the RP-1 fuel and liquid oxygen as oxidizer, and how much of that will it use to get to a certain point?

I don't know how i would calculate something like this. And the price of RP-1 is something I can't get a good answer on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SpaceX doesn't publish this, but [Spaceflight101](http://spaceflight101.com/spacerockets/falcon-heavy/) usually has pretty good estimates for this sort of data.

Core and boosters, each:

> LOX Mass  287,430 kg
>   RP-1 Mass     123,570 kg

Second stage:

> LOX Mass*     75,200kg
>   RP-1 Mass*    32,300kg

The cost of fueling a Falcon 9 [is in the region of \$200,000](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8330/what-is-the-cost-breakdown-for-a-falcon-9-launch) (for LOX plus RP-1), so a Falcon Heavy would be 2.5 times that, or \$0.5 million.

LOX costs in the region of \$0.20/kg, so (using the \$200k figure above) RP-1 would then be \$1,20/kg.

Comment: is the 0.5 mil. included in the 90 million they need for each launch?

Comment: @Pjotr: I think they _ask_ for $90 million, but that's income not cost.

Comment: @MSalters To nitpick, that would be the price or revenue (income is after expenses).

Comment: @chrylis Income is ambiguous - it can mean revenue (pre expenses) or earnings (net expenses.)

Comment: This is a great example of why fuel efficiency is much less of a concern than re-usability from a cost standpoint. (it is a big deal when considering delta v however) A major portion of the cost is the initial (and continuing) engineering, initial manufacturing, and servicing in-between flights.

Comment: @Pjotr [Here's an interesting estimate of the costs involved in a SpaceX launch](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/62sq7z/cost_calculation_for_falcon_9_falcon_heavy/). It's just an estimate, but it gives some perspective of all the costs which go into even a reusable rocket. It's not gas-n-go.

Comment: Is LOX really cheaper than RP-1?